# Autoproxy under windows?

Tags: windows, firefox, google-chrome, internet-explorer, proxy

Is there any software that allow us to choose which website to proxy and which one not commonly for Firefox/Chrome/IE/Other software? Is this possible with configuring the IE connection options?

thanks.

Comment: sorry i posted a solution before i noticed windows...deleted it

Comment: @aking1012: never matters.

Comment: These are 2 separate questions and should be broken up.

Comment: @Joe: Thanks for your advice. I have updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

Try [FoxyProxy](http://getfoxyproxy.org/index.html) on FireFox (I think it works with other XULRunner-based apps, too).  You can get as sophisticated as you'd like with it, or stick to very simple/simplistic rules.  I've been using it for years with very, very few issues.

Comment: thanks for your adivce but I'm using autoproxy on firefox now, and it works perfectly.